# Bakery Inventory Calculations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a Bakery inventory that lists the total amount of ingredients needed for the day by taking in:

- Cookie orders from Customers [2 Dozen Sugar Cookies, 1 Dozen Oatmeal Cookies]
- Cookie ingredients [Sugar Cookie: 1 cup sugar, etc.]

[See a chart here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ES92.png)

How would you recommend storing cookie ingredients? My initial thoughts were a hash.

{
    flour: 2.75,
    sugar: 1,
    . . .
}

Answer (score 1):

Why a hash?

You lose the benefits of a relational DB then, e.g, if someone edits the "Sugar" ingredient, your hash is no longer up-to-date. That *may* be okay, but you'll still have to deserialize and do the math.

Consider instead (pseudo-code):

```
Recipe => has_many :quantities
Quantity => has_one :ingredient
Order => has_many :recipes # Or whatever; you get the idea
```

Then you can query for a day's orders' quantities, group by ingredient, and do the math.

If you want to keep the hash you could use ingredient IDs as the key etc.

If you're already using a NoSQL DB then none of the above really applies and you have another set of options to choose from, although in some ways you end up with the same questions.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. I'm learning Rails, and this is my first test project for Rails. Do you have any resource/example recommendations to get a better understanding of Active Record Associations?? I found this: [RoR Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: @Alex The guides are the canonical source for information, but http://www.railstutorial.org/ is probably a better place to get started since it actually applies the docs to a real problem.